# modal logic, derive diamond from box

Tags: logic, modal-logic

I should derive $\lozenge$ from the semantics for $\square, \neg$ with classical reasoning at the meta-level:

Using the definitions:

$v_{\mathcal{M}}(\square F,w) = 1 \text{ if } \forall u (wRu \Rightarrow v_{\mathcal{M}}(F,u) = 1)$ and 0 otherwise

$v_{\mathcal{M}}(\lozenge F,w) = 1 \text{ if } \exists u (wRu \text{ and } v_{\mathcal{M}}(F,u) = 1)$ and 0 otherwise

Starting with:

$\forall u (wRu \Rightarrow v_{\mathcal{M}}(F,u) = 1)$  1. definition of $\square$

$\neg \forall u (wRu \Rightarrow \neg v_{\mathcal{M}}(F,u) = 1)$ 2. introducing $\neg$

$\neg \forall u (\neg wRu \text{ or } \neg v_{\mathcal{M}}(F,u) = 1)$ 3. using $p \Rightarrow q \Leftrightarrow  \neg p\lor q$

$ \exists u ( wRu \text{ and } v_{\mathcal{M}}(F,u) = 1)$ 4. solving $\neg$

Is that correct reasoning on the meta-level? I am not sure but I think my Professor mentioned that this procedure should take 8 steps. Am I missing something?

Comment: That is not how you introduce negation (step 2).

Answer (score 1):

What you need to show is that: when $\nu_\mathcal M(\square F, w)=1$ then $\nu_\mathcal M(\lozenge\lnot F, w)=0$.

Start by making the assumptions that $\nu_\mathcal M(\square F, w)=1$ and $\nu_\mathcal M(\lozenge\lnot F, w)=1$.  Next apply the definitions and thus show that these assumptions are contradictory.

Comment: Why do i need to show it like that? Wouldn't it be sufficient do derive $v_{\mathcal{M}}(\neg \square \neg F,u)$ from $v_{\mathcal{M}}( \square F,u)$?

Comment: Because that would not derive $\lozenge$ from $\square$.  Unless you meant to say $\nu_\mathcal M(\lnot\lozenge\lnot F, u)=1$, which *would* work.

Comment: hm now I am completely confused, do you have some reading material on this?